# Can anyone please tell me the time complexities of these following two java codes (a) & (b)

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

*I'm confused with the time complexities of these two codes:*

**code 1:**

I suppose its O(n^3)

```
void easy(in n, int x, inty) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<n: ++i) { //o(n)
        if(x<y) {
            for(int k=0: k < n*n: ++k) { //o(n^2)
                System.out.println("k =" +k);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("i =" +i);
        }
    }
}
```

**code 2:**

```
void find(int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<20; ++i) {   //o(1)
        for(int j=0: j<n; ++j) {   //o(n)
            for(int k=0; k<j; ++k)   //o(n)
                System.out.println("k =" +k);

            for(int m=0; m<i; ++m) //o(1)
                Systen.out.println("m =" +m);
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose its o(n^2)

Comment: Maybe if you explained how you arrived at these proposed answers, and what about them you do not trust, you might get more useful information.

Comment: Note that `O !== 0` and `O !== o`

Comment: oh ok, I'll do that.. Actually this is the first time I asked a question on this website so wasn't really sure what to write like comments and stuff :(

Comment: @Ayesha have a look at the question I referred to, it's a good intro to big O

Comment: @fvu Thanks! that link is really helpful..

Comment: Your code is full of typos and doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet you have an outer loop of `n` iterations. Then the body of that loop either performs `n^2` operations (if `x<y`) or one operation (if `x>=y`). This means that the running time is either `O(n)` or `O(n^3)`, depending on the values of `x` and `y`.

In the second snippet you have an outer loop with an `i` variable that doesn't depend on `n`. It goes from `1` to `20`, which means you can count it as constant amount of time, so lets get rid of that loop.

We have the following loops remaining:

```
for(int j=0: j<n; ++j) {
    for(int k=0; k<j; ++k)
        System.out.println("k =" +k);

    for(int m=0; m<i; ++m)
        Systen.out.println("m =" +m);
}
```

Now the outer loop has `n` iterations. The second inner loop depends on `i`, which is constant, so that entire loop takes constant time.

The first inner loop takes `O(n)`, since `k` goes from `0` to `j`, and `j` goes from `0` to `n`. Hence the total running time is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Aha ok.. Thanks alot!!